# How to reverse a structure in text file with C?

Tags: reverse

I have an exercise and I don't know how to solve it well!
I want write a C program that give from user the information of a student and then save it to file A.txt. After that reverse the first name, last name and student number and save it to file B.txt.

For example: 
john
lopez
123456

It changes to: 
nhoj
zepol
654321

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 50

struct student {
    char fname[SIZE];
    char lname[SIZE];
    char num[SIZE];
}st;

int main()
{
    FILE *in, *out;
    char ch;
    int tmp=0,flag=0,i;

    printf("INPUT First name: ");
    scanf("%s", &st.fname);

    printf("INPUT Last name: ");
    scanf("%s", &st.lname);

    printf("INPUT personal num: ");
    scanf("%s", &st.num);

    in= fopen("A.txt", "w");
    fputs(st.fname, in);
    fputs(st.lname, in);
    fputs(st.num, in);
    fclose(in);

    in= fopen("A.txt", "r");
    out=fopen("B.txt", "w");

    fgets(st.fname, strlen(st.fname)+1,in);
    strrev(st.fname);
    fputs(st.fname, out);
    printf("\n%s", st.fname);

    fgets(st.lname, strlen(st.lname)+1, in);
    strrev(st.lname);
    fputs(st.lname, out);
    printf("\n%s", st.lname);

    fgets(st.num, strlen(st.num)+1, in);
    strrev(&st.num);
    fputs(st.num, out);
    printf("\n%d", st.num);

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It's my code. My code can get the strings in file A.txt, then reverse them and after that, copy them in B.txt But I have a problem: How can I write in both files line by line? It means that write Firstname, Lastname and student number in 3 lines(in A.txt) and copy the reverses strings in 3 lines.(in B.txt)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the data to a file, then you first need to put the data in some dynamic memory allocation and then after reversing the content required in dynamic memory, you need to copy it into your file.

Comment: What do you means exactly i have to do first? you mean: int *data= malloc(sizeof(char)); data=st.fname;

Comment: see, the thing is you dont open any file initially. give ur inputs through scanf, then make them reverse, and then start writing the data into the file character by character.     yes, you can do it using malloc fuction as you said or you can do it as i said above

Comment: I changed my code in first post and explain about my new problem! I'll waiting for ur help...

Answer (score 1):

this is the program to reverse the each word in given string
    #include 
    #include

```
void reverse_string(char*);
void reverse_words(char*);

int main() {
char a[100];

gets(a);

reverse_words(a);

printf("%s\n", a);

return 0;
 }

void reverse_words(char *s) {
 char b[100], *t, *z;
 int c = 0;

  t = s;

  while(*t) {                           //processing complete string
   while(*t != ' ' && *t != '\0') {    //extracting word from string
    b[c] = *t;
  t++;
  c++;
 }
 b[c] = '\0';
 c = 0;

 reverse_string(b);        // reverse the extracted word

 z = b;

 while (*z) {    //copying the reversed word into original string
  *s = *z;
  z++;
  s++;
 }

 while (*s == ' ') {                 // skipping space(s)
  s++;
 }
/*
 * You may use if statement in place of while loop if
 * you are assuming only one space between words. If condition is
 * used because null terminator can also occur after a word, in
 * that case we don't want to increment pointer.
 * if (*s == ' ') {
 *   s++;
 * }
 */
 t = s;                              // pointing to next word
  }
  }

 /*
 * Function to reverse a word.
  */

 void reverse_string(char *t) {
 int l, c;
 char *e, s;

  l = strlen(t);
 e = t + l - 1;

  for (c = 0; c < l/2; c++) {
  s  = *t;
  *t = *e;
  *e = s;
  t++;
   e--;
  }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you can try using fputc, i.e., reading char by char along with a loop to get your data line by line as 3 lines.

```
char *ch;
for(i=0;st.fname[i];i++)
{
ch=getc(st.fname[i]);
fputc(ch,in);
}
```

repeat the same even for st.lname and st.num